# While loop does not stops while condition is false

Tags: php, while-loop

In the following code snippet while loop does not stops while condition become false.

```
public function isCircularDependancy($taskId, $newParentId){
        global $pdoHandlerObject;
        $task = $this->getTaskById($taskId);
        if($newParentId == 0){ // This is root task there is no parent
            return false;
        }

        if($task->parent_id == $newParentId){ // Parent is not changed
            return false;
        }

        $currentParentId = $newParentId;
        while($currentParentId != 0){
            if($currentParentId == $task->id){
                return true;
            }
            $currentParent = $this->getTaskById($currentParentId);
            $currentPatentId = $currentParent->parent_id;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: it won't stop unless `$currentParentId != 0` is false

Comment: at which line it must stop?

Comment: Typo: `$currentPatentId` !== `$currentParentId`

Comment: actually i have tasks with child parent relationship, i am looping over a child parents for example a->b->c->d, i am looping from "d" to "a" expecting while loop will stops once it reaches to "a" since "a" dont have any parent means it's parent id is 0. Hope this will make sense. Thank you.

Comment: What values do you get for `$currentParentId` if you place a breakpoint in the while loop or print the variable using `error_log` or `var_dump` etc?

Comment: @jeroen, really it was a typo, simple mistake but bothered me a lot. Thank you.